# Multiple domain names with pages linking to one website

Tags: seo, domains, registration

I work for a company who have been redesigning their company website.

I have been asked to register loads of domain names that contain the keywords that they want to use on the original site.  Each of these domain names will contain a one page website with a destription of what the company offers and a link saying something along the lines of 'click here for more infmormation' which then takes you to the main site.

The idea being the main site will then be recieving a lot of inbound links and hopefully rise in the google rankings, not to mention bring in more customers who have come to the site from all the other domain names who wouldn't have normally got to the website because it wasn't ranked on the first page.

Is this a good idea or will Google see this as spam and penalise the main site for having loads of links to it from one page websites hosted on the same nameserver?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad idea because:

1) It does risk appearing to be a link farm or some other form of manipulation to Google. And that's because it is doing exactly that. This is exactly the kind of stuff is cracking down on.

2) Those websites will have no SEO value because they will be weak one page sites with virtually no SEO value themselves (no internal links, almost certainly few no no incoming links, etc). Thus links from them will have extremely little value as well. So they may create quantity of links this way but the quality won't be there and that's what actually matters.

The odds of those mini sites ranking well is extremely small. The only chance they would have to rank well is if they are targeting long tail keywords. But in those cases any internal page on the main website can accomplish the same thing and probably do it better because of the internal linking you can take advantage of.

Comment: Agree, many people overlook the inbound link issue with single page domain-rankers.

Comment: A recommendation from a a nobody is worth nothing. 100 such recommendations are still worth nothing. So all the links in the world from sites with zero google juice are doing nothing to create google juice.

Answer (score 2):

This is a "halfway there" solution that a lot of reputable SEO's utilize. The problem is that there doesn't seem to be any time taken to build up the sites, and having only one page doesn't help either.

Google ranks keyword oriented domains very well if they are built correctly. If there is mid-to-low competition for a keyword phrase it's very easy to build up a little site and then send yourself inbound links. The key here is **quality**, if the one page site doesn't actually discuss the keyword phrase and semantically related topics you'll just look like spam. You won't be punished for this unless you're doing hundreds of sites like this, but you'll also be wasting your time.

The other thing you're missing is that the inbound link needs to point into the main site, i.e., "For more information on keyword phrase click here. By anchoring "Click Here" you're not actually getting a keyword related link, just a general link.

Remember, quality rules. Even if you see decent results from this type of SEO work, it won't last. Worse still, people might click the link and see that it's a bunch of garbage, then avoid your site in the future.